# Bash - loop through array of objects and combine them

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I'm trying to create a for-loop to go through all the items from an array, and add the items to a string. The tags are given as a single string with format "tag1 tag2 tag3", and the tagging parameter can be given as many times as I want with the single command with syntax "-tag tag1 -tag -tag2 -tag tag3". I'm unable to create a for loop for the job, and I'm a little confused what is wrong with my code.

```
TAGS="asd fgh jkl zxc bnm" # Amount of tags varies, but there is always at least one
ARRAY=($TAGS)
TAGSTOBEADDED=""
for i in "$ARRAY[@]"
do
  STRINGTOBEADDED="-tag ${ARRAY[$i]}"
  $TAGSTOBEADDED=$TAGSTOBEADDED+$STRINGTOBEADDED
done
command $TAGSTOBEADDED
```

Comment: `$ARRAY[@]` should be `${ARRAY[@]}`, otherwise it'll expand to the 0th element in array foolowed by `[@]`

Answer (score 0):

First, your array sintax is wrong as @oguz ismail said. To iter through array items you shold use this:

```
for i in "${ARRAY[@]}"; { echo $i;}
```

Second `$TAGSTOBEADDED=$TAGSTOBEADDED+$STRINGTOBEADDED` this is also fail.
Variables are set like so `var="$var 123"` you don't need $ in front of var name if you want to change it. Back to code. In this example you dont even need an array, just use `TAGS` var(without ""):

```
for i in $TAGS; { TAGSTOBEADDED+="-tag $i"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First: avoid storing lists of things in space-delimited strings (as you're currently doing with `TAGS` and `TAGSTOBEADDED`) -- there are a bunch of things that can go wrong if they have any "funny" characters (or if `IFS` gets changed). Use an array instead. Storing them as a string and then converting doesn't help; all of the same potential problems apply during the conversion.

I also recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names in scripts, since there are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings, and accidentally using one of those for something else can have weird effects. So, to define the array of tags, I'd just use this:

```
tags=(asd fgh jkl zxc bnm)
```

You also have a number of syntax errors in the script. In this line:

```
for i in "$ARRAY[@]"
```

... the shell will try to expand `$ARRAY` as a plain variable (not an array), and then treat "`[@]`" as just some unrelated characters that go after it. You need braces around the variable refence (like `"${ARRAY[@]}"`) any time you're doing anything nontrivial with a variable reference. BTW, this idiom -- including double-quotes, braces, square-brackets and at-sign -- is what you almost always want when getting the contents of an array.

In this line:

```
STRINGTOBEADDED="-tag ${ARRAY[$i]}"
```

`$i` will expand to one of the array elements, *not* its index. That is, it'll expand to something like:

```
STRINGTOBEADDED="-tag ${ARRAY[asd]}"
```

...which doesn't make any sense. You just want

```
STRINGTOBEADDED="-tag $i"
```

...except you don't want that either, because (as I said before) storing lists of things space-delimited in a string is a bad idea. But I'll get to that because fixing it will involve the next line:

```
$TAGSTOBEADDED=$TAGSTOBEADDED+$STRINGTOBEADDED
```

There are two problems here: you don't want a dollar sign on the variable being assigned to (`$varname` *gets* the value of a variable; anytime you're setting it, don't use the `$`). Also the `+` isn't needed to add strings, you just stick them end to end. Well, you'd need to add a space in between, something like one of these:

```
TAGSTOBEADDED=$TAGSTOBEADDED" "$STRINGTOBEADDED
TAGSTOBEADDED="$TAGSTOBEADDED $STRINGTOBEADDED"
```

(Generally, you should have double-quotes around all variable references; on the right side of a plain assignment is one of the few places it's safe to leave them unquoted, but I tend to prefer to just double-quote always rather than try to remember all of the exceptions about where it's safe and where it isn't. Plus, quoting just the space looks weird.)

But you don't want to do that either, because (again) space-delimited strings are a bad way to do things. Use an array. So before the loop, create an empty array instead of an empty string:

```
tagstobeadded=()
```

...and then inside the loop, append to it with `+=( )`:

```
tagstobeadded+=(-tag "$i")
```

...and then at the end, use it with all the appropriate quotes, braces, etc:

```
command "${tagstobeadded[@]}"
```

So, with all of these changes, here's what I'd recommend:

```
tags=(asd fgh jkl zxc bnm)
tagstobeadded=()
for i in "${tags[@]}"
do
  tagstobeadded+=(-tag "$i")
done
command "${tagstobeadded[@]}"
```